# limiting execution of onclicklistener code

Tags: java, android

So I have a series of imageViews within a relative layout. Each imageView has an onClickListener that will change the background color of other imageViews according to separate code if any imageViews is clicked on.

As of now, the background colors of affected imageViews remain changed even when other imageViews are clicked, leading to ask the imageViews eventually becoming highlighted as iIcouch on more and more imageViews.

I'd like to make it so that if another imageView is clicked on, then highlights cause by a previously clicked on imageview will disappear.

Not sure where to begin in tackling this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to help us help you :)

Comment: When an ImageView is clicked, do you want to reset all other ImageViews to a specific color. If so, what color would that be? e.g. their original color?